# tailspin spyworks delete object error

Tags: asp.net

My project is working but for it to work i had to take out the deleteobject(myitem)
as it kept showing up as an error, i have included my code below and the error that appears beside the text

```
 public void RemoveItem(string cartID, int productID)
    {
        using (CommerceEntities1 db = new CommerceEntities1())
        {
            try
            {
                var myItem = (from c in db.ShoppingCarts where c.CartID == cartID && c.ProductID == productID select c).FirstOrDefault();
                if (myItem != null)
                {
                    db.DeleteObject(myItem); 
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

**the error says that data accesscommerceEntities does not contain a definition for delete object and no extension method delete object**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sour but this problem happened when there is no primary key